# Sublime Theme Color (quote within quote)

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

For Sublime themes, how can I, or can I customize my theme for colors of a single/double quote within a double/single quote, respectively?

So for example, this "quote might be blue where 'this is green'".

Currently using Sublime Text 2 with a slight variation from [the Railscast theme](https://github.com/tdm00/sublime-theme-railscasts).

This is the code snippet from the theme that I suspect I need to modify, somehow?

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>String</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>string</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#A6E22E</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Double-Quoted String</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>string.quoted.double</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#0000FF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Single-Quoted String</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>string.quoted.single</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#00FF00</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This won't work for every language, as not all language definitions differentiate between single- and double-quoted strings, but for those that do (like HTML and PHP, for example) you should now have double-quoted strings in blue and single-quoted ones in green. Of course, feel free to play around with the colors' hex values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is slightly different than I'm looking for.  See, I would like to get "my quote in blue text with an inner single 'quote in green' and then the rest blue".  The above will only distinguish colors for single/double completely, it doesn't account for nesting.

Comment: @yekta The language definition (`.tmLanguage` file) would need to support nesting, and I'm not aware of any that do, although some may. What language(s) are you working with?

Comment: Ruby, Python, Javascript, HTML, CSS are the main ones.